# How can I put a programm into windows startup

Tags: windows, startup

Can I put a programm in the Windows startup? I already tryed opening the Task-Manager and putting it in there, but that doesen't work at all. Is there any other way I can do it?

Regards
-Timo Werner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the startup folder by typing `windows + r` and then writing `shell:startup` Hit enter and you can place the file there. Keep in mind that it opens after a bit of delay.